# How do I select TD in current div element using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I can't for the life of me figure out the correct selector syntax to get this to work.

I have a div element. Using `$(this)`, how would I select a `<TD>` that has a `class="stock"`, but only within `$(this)` div element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
$(this).find('td.stock');
```

Or, alternatively, pass `this` as an context to the `$()` method:

```
$('td.stock', this);
```

Both do the same thing.